# Inheritance of abstract class use another Type than defined for property

Tags: c#, inheritance, abstract-class

I created the following abstract class:

```
public abstract class AbstractClass
{
    public abstract string Name { get; set; }
    public abstract object Value { get; set; }
}
```

Now I want to derive two classes of the abstract class. I want to use an `enum` instead of the type `object`. My derived classes look like this:

First class:

```
public class InheritanceClass1:AbstractClass
{
    public override string Name { get; set; }
    public override FirstEnum Value { get; set; }
}
```

Second class:

```
public class InheritanceClass2 : AbstractClass
{
    public override string Name { get; set; }
    public override SecondEnum Value { get; set; }
}
```

I'm getting an error showed in my code, that the type of the property Value isn't `object`. I tryed to use the `new`-keyword instead of `override` like this:

In my abstract class:

```
public object Value { get; set; }
```

In my derived class:

```
public new FirstEnum Value { get; set; }
```

But if I create a `List<AbstractClass>` I have the problem that I can't use it for example for Linq because I would retrieve the "wrong" property. It is just hided, but still there, so I have to override the property.

So how do I have to change my abstract class and my derived classes, that I can use different types in my derived classes?

Comment: If you have a `List<AbstractClass>` then that may contain a mixture of different instances of different concrete types. So what type are you going to make the variable that obtains `Value`, if not `object`?

Comment: I want to use different `enums` as type for Value

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can use `abstract` class like this:

```
public abstract class AbstractClass<T>
{
    public abstract string Name { get; set; }
    public abstract T Value { get; set; }
}
```

And derived class will change like this:

```
public class InheritanceClass1 : AbstractClass<FirstEnum>
{
    public override string Name { get; set; }
    public override FirstEnum Value { get; set; }
}
```

If you know that you will need only `enums`, you can add `struct, IConvertible` restriction to `T`:

```
public abstract class AbstractClass<T> where T : struct, IConvertible
{
    public abstract string Name { get; set; }
    public abstract T Value { get; set; }
}
```

**Update** based on comment:

Not the cleanest solution if you need `List<AbstractClass>`, but you can have additional class:

```
public abstract class AbstractClass
{
    public abstract string Name { get; set; }
    public abstract int GetValue ();
}
```

Which will then be inherited by `AbstractClass<T>`:

```
public abstract class AbstractClass<T> : AbstractClass where T : struct, IConvertible
{
    public abstract T Value { get; set; }
}
```

And `InheritancClass`:

```
public class InheritanceClass1 : AbstractClass<FirstEnum>
{
    public override string Name { get; set; }
    public override FirstEnum Value { get; set; }

    public override int GetValue () => (int)Value;
}
```

And then you can use it in a list:

```
var list = new List<AbstractClass> { new InheritanceClass1 (), new InheritanceClass2 () };
```

In this way you can use `List<AbstractClass>` with `GetValue` method. If you are using only `enums` you can always recast it to `enum` value. Ofcorse, you would not know exactly which `enum` it is, but you can add additional field for that.

Comment: But, of note is that you won't be able to have a `List<AbstractClass>` now. You can of course have a `List<AbstractClass<FirstEnum>>` or a `List<InheritanceClass1>` but that's probably not why they had a `List<AbstractClass>` in the first place.

Comment: var `list` contains just `null` values if I use your code. If I use the `enum` instead of `IConvertible` I get some values, but this would work just for one `enum`